# How to toggle HUD?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

HUD can be disabled and restored by typing `tm` into the console, but the command disables the entire interface, including menus. A hotkey would also be more convenient.
Most likely not possible within the game, but there may be a suitable [mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/) available.

Comment: @Mazura: The mod doesn't have a toggle feature, but disables HUD components entirely according to the description.

Comment: I know some games allow you to bind keys to commands... I don't _know_ if Oblivion has it, but _maybe_ it does?

Comment: Oblivion, and most Bethesda games, have the option to run a .bat file containing console commands. I can't seem to find anything on it, but if you could create a .bat file with just a `tm` command in it, then find a way to hotkey that, it could be what you're looking for. To the best of my knowledge though, without some sort of mod, Oblivion doesn't support extra hotkeys aside from what's in-game already.

Comment: In fact, looking more into the nature of hotkeys in Oblivion, they're meant more for in-game items and spells than anything else. The chances of assigning a .bat command, or even the console command itself, seem slim to none due to limitations on the game.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: I can most likely create an Autohotkey script - but as I said the `tm` command isn't preferred as I'd like to play without HUD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Menu and Camera Toggler mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/39435/?tab=description) — HUD toggle is mapped to the <kbd>H</kbd> key by default and disabling doesn't turn off the UI elements, unlike the `tm` command. [Flying Camera Mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/12556?tab=description) is a potential alternative.

[source](http://www.gamesas.com/toggle-hud-crosshair-t174326.html) (retrieved the tesnexus.com pages with Wayback Machine)

Answer (score -1):

Use [BTMod 2.2](http://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/1825/?tab=1&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Foblivion%2Fajax%2Fmoddescription%2F%3Fid%3D1825%26preview%3D&pUp=1). From a reply on [no HUD](http://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/4101/?tab=4&&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Foblivion%2Fajax%2Fcomments%2F%3Fmod_id%3D4101%26page%3D1%26sort%3DDESC%26pid%3D0%26thread_id%3D20416&pUp=1) (a different mod):

Open the prefabs/menu/hud_mainmenu.xml file with notepad, and each time there's a number with alpha in the line, you replace it with 0.

It'll make every single element invisible like typing tm in the console, except you can still talk to people, loot and otherwise play as if the hud is turned on.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: The guide is for Fallout 4, the game doesn't even share the same engine (Creation Engine) with Oblivion (Gamebryo).

Comment: Do you have personal experience with Oblivion? `tm` **disables UI**, I can't even see the pause menu with the command enabled: https://i.imgur.com/jJLjCRb.png

Comment: @Mazura: You just said "the command disables the entire interface" OP is incorrect. It's the console being open that disables the UI, not the `tm` command.". I have closed the console, of course, and there is no UI. I really can't understand.

Comment: When you said "entire interface" I thought your problem was inputs not responding. More like *all the menus*. You want *just* the hud gone.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but I specifically asked how to toggle HUD, not how to disable. I'm looking for an easy way to set it on and off mostly for screenshot purposes. Editing game files involves manual work and most likely requires restarting the game as the files are in use when the game is running.